# google analytics keywords are missing? How do I get to them?

Tags: google-analytics

I don't log in much to google analytics, but it seems that they have removed the feature to view site visits by search terms.

Or has this moved to some strange hiding place? Help anyone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Traffic Sources -> Search -> Overview then click on Keyword in Primary Dimension.

[image]